# Vue.js App Element update data

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to have a template in `App.vue` which is main component of my app and it contains navigation bar. However I would like to hide this bar when in login page, but I cannot force `App.vue` to update. Any help please? :)

App.vue  - here I would like to have a flag if I should show toolbar and I want to use it in template. The main problem is that currentRoute.path doesn't get updated automatically. I also tried adding `router.afterEach`, but didn't manage to make it work.

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data() {
      return {
        msg: 'initial',
        showToolbar: router.currentRoute.path !== '/login'
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

main.js

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  if (!app) {
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      components: {App},
      template: '<App/>',

    })
  }
});
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
});

export default router;
```

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently setting up the **initial value** of `showToolbar`, but not setting it up to *watch for route changes*. For that to work, move `showToolbar` to the `computed` section of you `App.vue` vm:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'initial',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showToolbar() { return this.$router.currentRoute.path !== '/login' }
  }
}
```

Also, since you are not explicitly importing router in App.vue, you access it in App.vue vm like `this.$router`, not like `router`.

Comment: It is  `this.$router` sine he is in App.vue unless the router instance is imported

Comment: This still doesn't work for me, when I change route, the value is not updated :(